# White grid icon appears while installing app in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, appicon

During installation, white grid icon appears and after installation app icon is shown. Is this default behaviour for adhoc apps?

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is default Behavior .

Comment: Is there a workaround to show the app icon while loading? @NajamUsSaqib

Comment: No, Its the Default behavior for app installation and its just for one time when app gets installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is default behavior for iOS applications.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Taylor's response. You will need to add icons to your application. To do that click on on `Assets.xcassets` and select `AppIcon` there. You will see a Image set with provided details of icon image sizes which you will need to add.

[image: IconPage]

If not found (or deleted by mistake) `AppIcon` can be added by clicking on **+** button at the bottom.

[image: Add AppIcon to Assets.xcassets.]

Once done you will be able to see a app icons on different devices sizes. Make sure to remove alpha from 1024x1024 size icon else that will cause issue when trying publish application on appstore.

I have [created an iOS program](https://github.com/rptwsthi/AlliOSIconsWithProperName) that takes 1024x1024 size icon image and create the sizes that are needed form AppIcon image set. Make sure to go through [Readme](https://github.com/rptwsthi/AlliOSIconsWithProperName/blob/master/README.md) to understand how to use this program.