# React native images/icons ideal format and dimensions

Tags: android, ios, react-native, graphics, expo

I am a bit naïve in mobile development and building a react native app via expo. Consider the following cases:

1. Images/Icons within app
2. App Icon
3. Splash Screen

Which **format** and **dimensions** of the images (used as icons) are ideal for android+ios. Do we need to define icons for every dpi (ldpi, mdpi, tvdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdp) OR **svg** (vector graphics) can be used instead. Which format has support for both IOS+android?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set app icon and splash separately.

**Android:** For android, yes all different dimensions are needed for app icon. you can use [this tool](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.cli%5B%E2%80%A6%5Dpe=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher) to generate icons. Image can be .png or .jpg.

Learn More:

- https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio
- https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-icons.html#usage

**iOS:** App Icons Sizes needed for iOS can be defined easily by this picture.

[image: Image Icon Size].

To understand how to set app icon for iOS in Xcode check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65823688/656600).

Comment: Thanks @rptwsthi. Can't we use vector graphics instead of creating separate icon for all dpi's? Also what about asset icons/images inside app?

Comment: No. These have to be static images. You can export png from you vector icon image using some online tool.

Comment: So I should ask the designer to give me all the icons in svg format. Later on I can easily convert them (via online tools) to .png and scale them into different sizes without losing the quality right?

Comment: That will work, but I think you must get the details from designer itself. He will have better hand on that.